# Getting string characters inside, and outside a set of brackets with string patterns in Lua?

Tags: regex, string, lua, lua-patterns

I'm trying to create a string pattern that will match both non-space characters, and all characters inside a set of brackets. For example, a sequence such as this:

```
local str = [[
    This [pattern] should [return both] non-space 
    characters and [everything inside] brackets
]]
```

Would print out `This`, `[pattern]`, `should`, `[return both]`, `non-space` ... etc. I've been going at this for a while, and came up with a very *close* solution that I know the problem to, but cannot seem to solve. Here's my attempt:

```
local str = [[
    This [pattern] should [return both] non-space 
    characters and [everything inside] brackets
]]

for s in string.gmatch(str, "%S+%[?.-%]?") do
    print(s)
end
```

The issue is that spaces should be allowed inside the brackets, but not outside. This would print something like: `This`, `[pattern]`, `should`, `[return`, `both]`, `non-space` ... etc

Notice that `[return` and `both]` are two different captures, opposed to returning `[return both]`. I'm still sort of new to string patterns, so I feel like there's a few options I could be overlooking. Anyway, if anyone is experienced with this sort of thing, I sure would appreciate some insight.

Comment: `for s in ("]"..str.."["):gsub("](.-)%[", function(x) return x:gsub("%s+", "\0") end):gmatch"%Z+" do print(s) end`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just to explain Egor's solution in the comment a bit, the key idea is to differentiate between whitespaces that are inside the brackets `[]` from the ones that are outside. This is accomplished by

- first `gsub`ing the whitespaces outside the brackets replacing it with `\0`.
- followed by `gmatch` over the string matching against non-null characters.

The null char `\0` is used as a sentinel since it's unlikely to clash with a legitimate character in the input text.

A variation to this approach is to replace the whitespace *inside* the bracket instead followed with matches against non-whitespace characters

```
for s in str:gsub("(%[.-%])",
                  function(x)
                    return x:gsub("%s+", "\0") 
                  end)
            :gmatch "%S+"
do
  print( (s:gsub("%z+", " ")) )
end
```

Note that you are creating intermediate strings during the parse. If the input string is long then so is the temporary intermediate string. For one-off matches this is probably okay. If you're dealing with more heavy-duty parsing I suggest checking out [LPEG](http://www.inf.puc-rio.br/~roberto/lpeg/re.html).

For example, the following lpeg.re grammar can parse the given input text

```
local re = require 're'

local str =
[[
    This [pattern] should [return both] non-space 
    characters and [everything inside brackets]
]]

local pat = re.compile
  [[
    match_all   <- %s* match_piece+ !.
    match_piece <- {word / bracket_word} %s*
    word        <- ([^]%s[])+
    bracket_word <- '[' (word %s*)+ ']'
  ]]

for _, each in ipairs{ pat:match(str) } do
  print(each)
  end
```

Outputs:

> This
>   [pattern]
>   should
>   [return both]
>   non-space
>   characters
>   and
>   [everything inside brackets]